# Assembly cmp instruction

Tags: assembly, cmp

The following cmp instruction is confusing me:

%eax,0x18(%esp,%ebx,4)

I know it's comparing arg1 to arg2, but what exactly is going on in arg2 with the stuff in parenthesis?

Thanks

Comment: The non-LSD infused version is cmp [esp + ebx*4 + 18h], eax

Answer (score 0):

It calculates the address of a memory location based on the values of esp and ebx. You didn't specify the assembly notation used, so I can just guess it's esp + 4*ebx + 0x18.

Answer (score 0):

That's an effective address in at&t syntax.
The general form is `displacement(base, index, scale)` where `displacement` is a number (address), `base` and `index` are registers, and `scale` is a factor of `1`, `2`, `4` or `8`.
The resulting address is calculated as `displacement + base + index * scale`. Components may be omitted.

By the way, you can switch gnu tools into intel syntax mode if you like that better.